# Does fresh garlic have any specialized uses?

Tags: garlic

I have some fresh garlic that I have just harvested from the allotment, and am drying out.  I notice that the fresh garlic has a different texture from the shop bought stuff, and I was wondering if there are things that are more suitable for fresh garlic?  Does it slow roast better?  Is it better to use raw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I love fresh (also called green) garlic. Some uses:

- For a quick, simple and delicious pasta sauce, chop a whole bulb of garlic (with peel and all) and sautee in some olive oil, rosmary and chili peppers. Add some white wine and reduce.
- Make a [soup](http://www.ambrosiac.net/recipes/soups/green_garlic_soup)
- Clean whole bulbs from dirt, remove the external peel, wrap in tinfoil, sprinkle some salt, olive oil and thyme and bake for an hour. The garlic will turn into a paste which you can then squeeze and spread on fresh loaves of bread.

Comment: Upvoted for baked-garlic-paste on fresh bread.  <drool>

Answer (score 3):

I find wet garlic (as freshly harvested garlic is sometimes known) makes a nicer garlic butter than its stored counter-part, which you can then keep for "quite a while" without spoiling -- depending on the size of the bulb, I'd normally use about two bulbs and some of the stalks for each pound of butter (or half kilo). I've kept prepared garlic butter in the fridge, and have used it all long before it has spoiled in the past, too.

Answer (score 1):

chop the tops off a few bulbs and put salt pepper olive oil and balslamic vinigar. Bake at 450 F for 30 mins, peel and eat!